# Clear between two tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to clear all text between tags `</form>` and `</body>` on click.
There appears some text with no id.

```
</form>
text text text
</body>
```

Comment: can you post code with all starting tags...like starting form tag and some sample data in between

Comment: Can wee see the complete HTML? with only this we can't help you because in the solution we need to act in regard on all other tags.

Comment: In normal javascript you could traverse these as nodes and look for the node that has a nodeType of 3 (which is for text) and remove that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var pa=document.body;
  while(pa.lastChild.tagName!="FORM"){
  pa.removeChild(pa.lastChild);
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution because it doesn't depend on being able to change the markup.  Provided that the final text node registers as a child, I do believe that is how the DOM deals with anonymous text nodes, so I think it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
</form>
<span id="mySpan" onclick="document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = '';">text text text</span>
</body>
```

Comment: I changed the quotes -- you had double quotes in getElement... call, but my edit needs to be peer reviewed apparently

Comment: Yea, thanks. I caught that and tried to fix it, but you already had. Thanks

Comment: as i said, text appears on page load with no id and other staff. I need to parse it somehow between </form> and </body> and delete.

Comment: That's what the span tags are for. You cannot do what you are asking without having some way to relate the text to a DOM element.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios That's not correct. Text, even outside of tags is a valid dom element.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios from the sample code given, you now that the node in question is the last text node in the body. It's rather simple to search for that given standard dom functions. (And if one wants to be even more precise, it's the last text-node in the body after the last form-node)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the html of the outer element with the html of the inner element:

```
<div id="div1">
    Outer
    <div id="div2">Inner</div>
    Outer
</div>

<div onclick="replace()">Clear</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function replace()
    {
        $("#div1").html( $("#div2").html() )
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That also removes any text before the form, question asks about text AFTER form, but that it's a final node.